# Are there any known models/techniques to determine whether a person in a store is a customer or a store representative?

Tags: computer-vision, image-recognition, reference-request, object-detection

Are there any known models/techniques to determine whether a person in a store is a customer or a store representative?

For example, customer representatives can wear uniforms and then one possible way to identify customer representatives is by the color of their uniform, texture, etc. On the other hand, a customer can also wear the same color clothes as that of a customer representative. Likewise, a customer representative could be wearing "normal clothes." So the main problems that may occur could be:

- A customer becomes misclassified as a customer representative.
- A customer representative representative becomes misclassified as a customer

So using clothing as the only proxy to classify people as customers or customer representatives seems to be flaky. Any other known ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Access to the back of the store, basically if you can track them entering and leaving an employees only area.

But this requires a really good tracking algorithm and if you lose track you're going to have to fall back on some other properties.